# Group and filter a list of objects in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays

The list of object is

```
list= [{app: "a1", company: "20", permission: "All"},
{app: "a1", company: "21", permission: "download"},
{app: "a2", company: "20", permission: "search"}]
```

Then I need to filter above list as

```
{
 "a1":{20:["All"],
       21:["download"]},
 "a2": {20:["search"]}
}
```

I'm using ES6. Thanks for your concern :)

Answer (score 2):

I should notice first, that Stackoverflow is resource that help in problem solving, it should not solve your tasks for you, it should help find problems in your solution.

```
list.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(item.app)) {
    acc[item.app] = {}
  }

  if (!acc[item.app].hasOwnProperty(item.company)){
    acc[item.app][item.company] = []
  }

  acc[item.app][item.company].push(item.permission)
  return acc
},{})
```